# What actually is capacitance?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, voltage, capacitance

Why the charge is proportional to voltage?
Why we measure charge per unit voltage?

The charge for unit voltage should also have unit value

I am very confused pls explain me

Comment: "The charge for unit voltage should also have unit value". No. $Q=CV$, so if  = 1 volt, then  = × 1 volt.

Comment: It might help if we knew what level of schooling you have.

Comment: "The capacitance is a function only of the geometry of the design (e.g. area of the plates and the distance between them) and the permittivity of the dielectric material between the plates of the capacitor. For many dielectric materials, the permittivity and thus the capacitance, is independent of the potential difference between the conductors and the total charge on them." ~ wikipedia,

Comment: Even for Coulomb's law charge is proportional to voltage, but is the OP familiar with it?

Answer (score 5):

Another analogy. Let's look at air in a closed container. The amount of air is equivalent to the charge, the pressure is the voltage. If you want more air, you either use a larger container (increase capacity) OR you just increase the pressure. If you double the pressure, there will be twice the amount of air in the container.

Answer (score 2):

"Why the charge is proportional to voltage?"

What level of answer, I wonder, do you want? For many purposes (for example for circuit theory), it's fine simply to know that we can show *by experiment* that $Q$ is proportional to $V$ for a capacitor. But you may want to know *why* this should be so. The answers of Odin and Hilmar give you analogies. The argument that most physicists use may be harder to follow than you would like, but it goes along these lines...

Let's assume a parallel plate capacitor, with equal and opposite charges, $±Q$, on the inner (facing) surfaces of its plates. Symmetry demands that, if the linear dimensions of the plates are much greater than their separation, then, except near the edges of the plates, the electric field between them will be uniform and directed from the positive plate towards the negative.
[image]

Gauss's law shows that the magnitude of the electric field strength, $E$, in the gap is
$$E=\frac Q {\epsilon_0 \epsilon_r A}$$
in which $\epsilon_0$ is the permittivity of free space, $\epsilon_r$ is the relative permittivity of the dielectric in the gap between the plates, and is almost equal to 1 for air, and $A$ is the area of each plate.

We find the potential difference between the plates by imagining a test charge, $q$ to be taken from one plate to the other. We can take it by any route, so we might as well take it straight across the gap. The force on $q$ will be of magnitude $qE$, so the work done on $q$ by the field as $q$ goes from one plate to the other will be
$$W=qE \times d\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{in which d is the distance between the plates}$$
Therefore the voltage (or potential difference ) between the plates is
$$V=\frac W q\ =\frac{qE \times d} q=Ed$$
So we have
$$Q=\frac{\epsilon_0 \epsilon_r A} d V$$
We see that $Q$ is proportional to $V$, with $\frac{\epsilon_0 \epsilon_r A} d$ as the proportionality constant. This proportionality constant is called the *capacitance* of the parallel plate capacitor.

We can show that the proportionality between $Q$ and $V$ applies for capacitors of a different geometry from that of parallel plates.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a silly example of humans in a small room.
Lets say you want to fit a lot of humans in a small room, What would you do, Obviously try to push them inside. You'd force them to stay inside using some kind of mysterious force (lets say you ask their teacher to guard the gate -"The mysterious force")
Now you want more people inside , But notice that there were some already inside .. You being crazy ordered them in so you appointed more guards on gate to force them in..
Now you need more people in (for some weird reason), you'd need more and more number of guards on the gate to not let them (people trapped inside) run away..

I guess by now you were able to click where I way going
Apply this analogy to electrons and Electric potential.
To have more electrons (effectively more charge) on a conductive plate you would need greater Electric Potential to not let those electrons run away...

I think now you understand why Q is proportional to V.
Now come to next part of your question
Why we measure charge per unit voltage..
We made experiments and observed that Q is proportional to V   so the proportionality constant in called C (capacitance)..
If you have some other questions then comment below

Comment: if you understand Hindi then check out Alakh Sir's lesson on youtube. class 12 physics chapter 2 Physics Wallah